# apt-get and add-apt-repository not working

Tags: keyboard, apt, repositories

When I try to use the command `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`, I get the output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chromium-browser : Depends: gconf-service but it is not installable
                    Depends: libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.5) but it is not installable
                    Depends: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra (= 55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263) but it is not going to be installed or
                             chromium-codecs-ffmpeg (= 55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263) but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: chromium-browser-l10n but it is not going to be installed
 elementary-tweaks-dbg : Depends: elementary-tweaks (= 1.0-0~232~ubuntu0.4.1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I use `apt-get -f install` I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

When I try to use `sudo add-apt-repository` I get the error `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`. I've tried `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` but I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
`
`
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 software-properties-common : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.96.20.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Also, it appears that when I press shift, I need to press the character I tried to capitalize a second time.

Answer (score 7):

Install Software Properties

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-software-properties : Depends: python-pycurl but it is not installable
                              Recommends: unattended-upgrades but it is not going to be installed
 python3-software-properties : Depends: python3-pycurl but it is not installable
                               Recommends: unattended-upgrades but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: I ran into the sudo apt-get-repository "command not found" problem with a freshly-installed version of Elementary as well, preventing my attempts to install the Vocal podcatcher (pretty much developed for Elementary). Your solution resolved matters nicely, thank you.

Comment: I don't know what I did but somewhere along the line I fixed it.