# How to install Flatpak?

Tags: ppa

I want to test Flatpak on elementary OS. Since it is built on top of Ubuntu 16.04, it should be possible to install flatpack. Like in flatpack installing guide.

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

It doesn't work.

So how to install Flatpak on Loki?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a PPA in Loki?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7507/how-can-i-add-a-ppa-in-loki)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're in the right track on installation of Flatpak on Elementary as indicated on [their guide](http://flatpak.org/getting.html). You might not be aware of it, but `add-apt-repository` is disabled by default on Elementary (to avoid reckless installation of PPAs). Workaround for that situation have been posted [multiple](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7507/how-can-i-add-a-ppa-in-loki) [times](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10775/fixed-unknown-solution-apt-get-and-add-apt-repository-not-working) on this site.

Basically, you can enable it via:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

After that, you can proceed to the usual Flatpak installation steps.